# Calendar Year Return Calculation

Tags: r, time-series, finance, xts

I am trying to calculate calendar year GDP growth for the `GDPC96` time series from FRED (i.e. for a xts object). I am looking for a simple function without loops which calculate the calendar year growth where the variables are the data object (here `GDPC96`), the frequency (here quarterly) and whether deprecated periods (such as 2013) shall be shown or not.

For example:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GDPC96",src="FRED")
a <- annualReturn(GDPC96,leading=FALSE)
tail(a)
```

I would like it to be such that the changes are per calendar year, i.e. it should calculate from 01.01.1947 to 01.01.1948 and so on. Then, for 2012, where data is only available through Oct, it should be omitted.

As far as I have seen none of the functions in PerformanceAnalytics and the related packages can do this properly.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've tried and an example of what you would like the output to be?

Comment: I did try it with annualReturn from quant mod by changing the "leading" entry. However, result was wrong.

Comment: How was it wrong?  What would you like the output to be?

Comment: I did try it with annualReturn from quant mod by changing the "leading" entry. However, result was wrong. In my R session, I did the following                                              library(quantmod)
a=annualReturn(GDPC96,leading=FALSE)                                          The result is the following (it always calculates from Oct. to Oct. because the last data point is Oct.2012)                                        yearly.returns
1947-10-01             NA
1948-10-01    0.041751844
...

Comment: What would you like the output to be?

Comment: I would like it to be such that the changes are per calendar year, i.e. it should calculate from 01.01.1947 to 01.01.1948 and so on. Then, for 2012, where data is only available through Oct, it should be deprecated. I have many other series with different start/end where the same basic problem appears.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want something like a year-over-year return calculation.  I'm not aware of a function that does this automatically, but it's easy to do with the `ROC` function in the TTR package.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GDPC96",src="FRED")
ROC(GDPC96, 4)  # 4-period returns for quarterly data
getSymbols("SPY")
spy <- to.monthly(SPY)
ROC(spy, 12)  # 12-period returns for monthly data
```

Update based on comments:

```
first.obs.by.year <- lapply(split(GDPC96, "years"),first)
last.obs.by.year <- lapply(split(GDPC96, "years"),last)
ROC(do.call(rbind, first.obs.by.year))
ROC(do.call(rbind, last.obs.by.year))
```

Comment: No, I look for the change over a calendar year, i.e the value of 01-01-1948 divided by the value of 01-01-1947 and so on (just one change per calendar year). In terms of pseudo code, this would mean: look for the last value per year (or the first value of a new year, depending on how data is stored) and divide it by the same value of the preceding year. No rolling every quarter or so. The code you suggested would not do that. Hope this clarifies matters

Comment: Thx. for this. When I execute the above code, I get still something different: 2006-10-01  0.0235019504
2007-10-01  0.0218121684
2008-10-01 -0.0337643335
2009-10-01 -0.0008136949
2010-10-01  0.0236561206
2011-10-01  0.0195210535
2012-10-01  0.0165570024, so it appears that there is still something wrong.

Comment: Saying "something's wrong" is entirely unhelpful. If you want people to help you solve a problem, you need to be more explicit about your desired result (as I've already asked you several times).

Comment: Sorry, sorry. I x-checked again and now it works. Many thanks for your help.